Dynamics 365 CE change rollup field minumum and maximum values
I need to change the Minimum Value and Maximum value of a rollup field after it's created.
Deleting the field is not an option for me (as it is a managed solution and the original solution is changed too much and installing an update is so complicated)
So I need to change the minimum value (it's set as 1 and when there are non related records , I cannot save the record)
I'm on an on-premises environment so :
Changing anything anything including editing SQL etc. is something worth to try for me.
Thanks

create a new rollup field and use the new one

Thanks, But this is a managed solution, the rollup is in place and it don't allow me to save the record, telling me the value is invalid(0).
